# Uninstalled libparted2. FIles application gone

Tags: 22.04

So i was trouble shooting an error I was getting when trying to install the pip lib pyparted. Telling me that libparted2 was not installed. So i had tried to uninstall libparted2 and reinstall it but when I uninstalled libparted2 my files application has gone and can't seem to get it back.

Please can someone help with this.

[image: Side Bar Picture]

[image: Applications Picture]

Comment: Please don't randomly uninstall applications without reading the terminal output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reinstall the files application with

```
sudo apt install nautilus
```